# Endpoint modification in SQL Server mirroring

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I have three `SQL Server 2008 R2` machines which are configure to be `Principal`, `Mirror` and `Witness`.

I need to move them to another subnet, therefore their IP addresses will change; and i had configure the mirror using the IPs and no their names.

My question is: if I just use `ALTER ENDPOINT` with the new ip address (or the name), would it keep rolling or it won't work?

I'd appreciate any advise.

Thanks!

Comment: You *can* do this, but you'll need to stop the endpoint and the start it again. There will be a small blip.

Comment: So, you mean..:
- Pause (or break?) the mirror
- Use the Alter Endpoint query
- Resume the mirror
Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Don't forget you'll need to change the endpoint on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of modifying the endpoints. This is the process:

- ALTER DATABASE IICS SET PARTNER OFF (Server2)
- Change IP address in Server2
- Change IP address in Witness
- Change IP address in Server1
- ALTER DATABASE IICS SET PARTNER = 'TCP://SERVER1:Port' (Server2)
- ALTER DATABASE IICS SET PARTNER = 'TCP://SERVER2:Port' (Server1)
- ALTER DATABASE IICS SET WITNESS = 'TCP://WITNESS:Port' (Server1)